# How to update at a specific row, after finding the same value in two tables

Tags: pandas, pandas-loc

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['xx'], ['4']] 
data2 = [['4', 'x0'], ['aa', 'bb'], ['cc', 'dd']]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=["isin"])
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=["isin", "data"])
print(df2)

df1.loc[df1['isin'] == df2['isin'], 'data'] = df2['data'] 
print (df1)  

# Exception has occurred: ValueError
# Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
# df1.loc[df1['isin'] == df2['isin'], 'data'] = df2['data']

# THIS IS IT NOW

# df1:
#   isin
# 0   xx
# 1    4

# df2:
#   isin data
# 0   4    x0
# 1   aa   bb
# 2   cc   dd
```

Problem:

1. algorithm find the row with the '4' - in column 'isin' in both df
2. pull from df2 the 'data' at this row (in this case 'x0')
3. add it to df1 - in this case(x0) - at the row of '4' at new column 'data'

```
# df1:             
#   isin           
# 0   xx           
# 1    4           

# df2:             
#   isin data      
# 0   4    x0      
# 1   aa   bb     
# 2   cc   dd   

# df3:
#   isin data
# 0   xx  NaN
# 1    4   x0
```

Comment: Where does 100 come from? It isn't in any of the dataframes...Your question could use better formatting and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with tranbi that the question needs more clarity. 100 is not in df1 anywhere. But, if you want to update just one cell in the dataframe, assuming we have this:

```
    years             isin  toast
0   55                 55     55
1   55                 55     55
2   this information    4     55
```

then

`df2.loc[df2['years']=='this information',['years']]='that information'`

will update just that cell. You could use df.loc instead of 'this information' to find the value in df1. Couldn't do it because that value doesn't exists in the example you gave so not quite sure that is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['xx'], ['4']] 
data2 = [['4', 'x0'], ['aa', 'bb'], ['cc', 'dd']]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=["isin"])
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=["isin", "data"])
print(df2)

# merge was the solution ive looked for

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left')  
print (df3)
```